# How to selectively ignore folders used for different Docker files inside the same project

Tags: docker

I work on a project which contains a frontend and backend in the same repository in different folders: `front` and `back`. I also use two different Docker files, `Dockerfile_front` and `Dockerfile_back`. And I use docker-compose to bring the project up and down.

I'd like to exclude `back` folder from the `Dockerfile_front` building context and vice versa.

What is the practical way to isolate docker contexts in such a case?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Why don't you just have a 'dockerfile' with the normal name in each directory? The docker compose file can have a build location for each image. If the two folders are siblings, then they should not be in each other's build context.

Comment: Absolutely! I'm embarrased, I couldn't see that by myself. Probably that happened 'cause I got used to current project structure. Anyway, thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a way to have two different `.dockerignore` files in the same directory that I'm aware of.

However, buildkit has recently entered into experimental in the latest releases and has the ability to only pull the parts of the build context needed for the specific build. So with buildkit, if you do not have a copy command that includes `back` in your front image, then that folder will not be included in the context, without you needing to specify it in your `.dockerignore` file.

Comment: Thank you for your help, BMitch. I found out I need no extra tool to achieve what I want. Going to delete my question soon. Sorry.